# Error code while Compiling in Knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I am new to Latex and was using the knitr. I have successfully compiled knitr files.  However, now that I finished my Rcode, I cannot get the LaTex to compile.

I really want to get this to work, but I don't know what the problem is.

```
Writing to file newhw3.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
 1 : echo keep.source term verbatim (newhw3.Rnw:9)
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
`stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
 2 : echo keep.source term verbatim (newhw3.Rnw:28)
Error in driver$finish(drobj) : 
  the output file 'newhw3.tex' has disappeared
Calls: <Anonymous> -> <Anonymous>
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Removed 24 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin). 
2: Removed 24 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin). 
Execution halted
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you were using Sweave instead of knitr.

Comment: I went into rstudio selected new file, then rsweave. what else could I do? The only options were rsweave, rhtml, rpresentation, rdocumentation.

Comment: go to the Tools/Global Options menu, click on the Sweave icon (6th down), select "Weave Rnw files using: [knitr]" in the first choice item